# Text from file, DB_query into a tuple or list, and get the difference between the two

Tags: python

I basically have this test2 file that has domain information that I want to use so I strip the additional stuff and get just the domain names as new_list.

What I want to then do is query a database with these domain names, pull the name and severity score and then (the part I'm really having a hard time with)  getting a stored list (or tuple) that I can use that consists of the pulled domains and severity score.

It is a psql database for reference but my problem lies more on the managing after the query.

I'm still really new to Python and mainly did a bit of Java so my code probably looks terrible, but I've tried converting to strings and tried appending to a list at the end but I am quite unsuccessful with most of it.

```
def get_new():
    data = []
    with open('test2.txt', 'r') as file:
        data = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('test2.txt')]
    return data

new_list = get_new()

def db_query():

    cur = connect.cursor()
    query ="SELECT name, de.severity_score FROM domains d JOIN ips i ON i.domain_id = d.id JOIN domains_extended de ON de.domain_id = d.id WHERE name = '"


    for x in new_list:
        var = query + x + "'"
        cur.execute(var)
        get = cur.fetchall()

# STORE THE LOOPED QUERIES INTO A VARIABLE OF SOME KIND (problem area)

    print(results)

    cur.close()
    connect.close()
db_query()
```

Happy place: Takes domain names from file, uses those domain names a part of the query parameters to get severity score associated, then stores it into a variable of some sort so that I can use those values later (in a loop or some logic).

I've tried everything I could think of and ran into errors with it being a query that I'm trying to store, lists won't combine, etc.

Comment: But what is the error for this code? I don't see anything particularly wrong, except that `connect` is undefined and that you should be using binding instead of composing the query as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Well first off in your code you are resetting your get variable in each loop.  So after fixing that by initializing `get = []` above your loop then adding `get.extend(cur.fetchall())` into your loop instead of the current statement. You could then do something like `domainNames = [row[0] for row in get]` . If get is loading properly though getting the values out of it should be no problem.

Comment: First off, I appreciate your quick response and help. 

The format that returns from the get query alone is [('domain.com', 4), ('domain2.com', 3)]  

With the way that you have it, it seems like it cuts off the severity score that is associated with the domain names.  
ie ['domain.com, 'domain2.com']

Half there~ hahaha

Comment: @BrianHartling just get rid of the ```[0]``` in ```[row[0] for row in get]```

Answer (score 0):

1. I would make sure that your get_new() function is returning what yous expect from that file. Just iterate on your new_data list.
2. There is no reference to results in your db_query() function (perhaps it is global like new_data[]) but try printing the result of the query, that is, `print(get)` in your for loop and see what comes out. If this works then you can create a list to append to.